# Sefarim on how Gematria works?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, gematria-numerology

While I know the basics of Gematria, i.e. the numerical value assigned to each letter, I’d like to learn more, like the different letter substitutions, how far off you can be and still count it as the same value, etc., as well as sources for these principles. Can someone recommend a Sefer on the topic?

Comment: Just like Chazal warn us about using the principle of _gezeirah shavah_, I think this caution should be stretched to fit _gematria_ as well. With all the rules that go into _gematria_, you can pretty much make it work with any word and get the outcome you want.

Comment: I recently saw an amazing Sefer on this very subject from a Rov in Haifa - I'll try find it again - please remind me in a few days if I forget.

Comment: 1. The intro. to [Rokeach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_of_Worms) on Torah. 2. [Hakdamah Shnia to Ittur Bikurim](https://books.google.com/books?id=2dRRAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP12#v=onepage&q&f=false) (commentary on Baal HaTurim).

Comment: see pardes rimonim by the ramak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The artscroll [Baal Haturim Chumash on Bereishis](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578191284.html) has an excellent introduction on gematrias, letter substitutions and such.